# The wagtail example of using entities isn't working for me

Tags: wagtail, draftail

The Wagtail example of using entities as given in this [page of documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/extending_draftail.html#creating-new-entities) isn't working for me.  I am following the third example of using Entities which is supposed to create a button for stock price but no button is appearing for me in the rich text field in the admin editor.  I have created a minimum reproducible example which demonstrates just this problem.  https://github.com/kiwiheretic/stockentity.  I am using Wagtail 4.1.1 which I understand is the latest version.

Can anyone help me see what I have missed and why the button doesn't appear as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This or a similar question was asked in the Wagtail Slack. To get the button to appear, it either needs to be included in the [features list when you create a new RichTextField](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#limiting-features-in-a-rich-text-field) OR you need to add it to the default configuration using the [WAGTAILADMIN_RICH_TEXT_EDITORS setting](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html#wagtailadmin-rich-text-editors).

Comment: I already did that.  DId you check the github repo?  You can see it in https://github.com/kiwiheretic/stockentity/blob/main/home/models.py

Comment: OK I see the python portions of the example code - but your stock.js is empty. Does the example work if you copy the react code from the example into https://github.com/kiwiheretic/stockentity/tree/main/home/static/js

Comment: Its not empty for me.  I had a look at https://github.com/kiwiheretic/stockentity/blob/main/home/static/js/stock.js and it contains 22 lines of code.